# what do i need to use dblp data set with sparql engine, how to set up the data with the engine

Tags: sparql, pdblp

I want to understand the process o using dblp dataset with sparql engine.
can anyone hep with the steps /not the queries

I downloaded the dblp data set but I don't know how to connect it with sparql engine

Comment: RDF data -> load into some triple store (and if you need also some triple store that does support SPARQL protocol via HTTP ) -> run query. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Almost 1 billion triples, AFAIK... Try to google already deployed SPARQL endpoints...